# Moditect not finding the current module when Jlinking

Tags: java, maven, jlink, moditect

I'm using [ModiTect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) to Jlink my Java application. Following the [README](https://github.com/moditect/moditect/blob/master/README.md) and the two examples, [undertow](https://github.com/moditect/moditect/blob/master/integrationtest/undertow/pom.xml) and [vert.x](https://github.com/moditect/moditect/blob/master/integrationtest/vert.x/pom.xml), I added this to my `pom.xml`:

```
<execution>
    <id>create-runtime-image</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <modulePath>
            <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
        </modulePath>
        <modules>
            <module>tech.dashman.dashman</module>
        </modules>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I'm also using ModiTect to inject `module-info.java`s into the dependencies that don't have them, but I think that is irrelevant to this question. When I run `mvn package` it fails with this error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Module tech.dashman.dashman not found
```

That is the module this pom.xml is for. Why is it not finding it (when the examples seem to indicate it would be found automatically)?

Adding a module path made it findable:

```
<modulePath>
    <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
    <path>${project.build.directory}/classes</path>
</modulePath>
```

but I had to point to the `classes` subdir in the `target` directory because if I point to `target` so that the `jar` file can be found, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Two versions of module tech.dashman.dashman found in C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\dashman\target (dashman-1.0.0-beta.2.jar and classes)
```

Comment: Can you file an issue with minimal yet complete pom.xml exposing this probelm? I can then try and take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry @Gunnar, I'm not working in this project anymore :(